# How to use assertions for multiple scenario in gatling?

Tags: karate

Right Now I am trying to do performance testing of all my api's.I already created one feature file having different scenarios(every scenario having different tag).Now I want to do use assertions on mean ResponseTime with different scenarios different assertions.

````
val Performance1 = scenario("Performance1").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/Testing1.feature@Performance"))
val Performance2 = scenario("Performance2").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/Testing2.feature@v3ContentMeta"))

val v4SearchTest = scenario("SearchTest").
group("SearchTesting") { exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/Testing1.feature@Performance"))
}

setUp(
  (Performance1.inject(rampUsers(10) over (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)),
    Performance2.inject(rampUsers(10) over (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  ).assertions(details("SearchTesting").responseTime.mean.lte(680))```
````

Comment: sure @PeterThomas.

Answer (score 3):

You can add Gatling assertions as Global asserts. This will perfectly work with Karate Gatling. This is a sample scenario which we tried

```
setUp(
    firstScenario.inject(
      nothingFor(5 seconds), // Pause for a given duration
      atOnceUsers(10), //Inject 10 Users at once
      constantUsersPerSec(10) during (20 seconds), // Induce 10 requests on every second and continues this process for 30 seconds
      rampUsers(10) over (10 seconds) // Linear Ramp up of the user
    ).protocols(protocol),

    secondScenario.inject(
      nothingFor(10 seconds), // Pause for a given duration
      atOnceUsers(20), // Inject 10 Users at once
      constantUsersPerSec(10) during (10 seconds), // Induce 10 requests on every second and continues this process for 40 seconds
    ).protocols(protocol),

    thirdScenario.inject(
      nothingFor(15 seconds), // Pause for a given duration
      rampUsers(20) over (1 minute) // Linear Ramp up of the user
    ).protocols(protocol),

    fourthScenario.inject(
      nothingFor(20 seconds), // Pause for a given duration
      constantUsersPerSec(10) during (20 seconds), // Induce 10 requests on every second and continues this process for 20 seconds
    ).protocols(protocol)

  ).assertions(
    global.responseTime.max.between(100, 5000),
    global.failedRequests.percent.is(0),
    global.successfulRequests.percent.gt(90)
  ).maxDuration(10 minutes) // Configuring the maximum duration of your simulation. It is useful when we need to bound the duration the simulation when we can’t predict it.
```

The global asserts will be displayed as a separate section in the Gatling reports. This is a useful feature of Karate Gatling. Test specific failures will also get displayed in the report of Karate Gatling. For example, if this is your scenario

```
Scenario: My First Sample Scenario
    Given url endpointUrl
    And header karate-name = 'Feature 1_Scenario3'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

And if the status code is not responded as 200, this also gets recorded in the Karate Gatling reports.

**Asserts in Gatling:** https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/assertions/#scope

Comment: thanks @Sree but what I am trying to do is let say I have 5 different scenarios and I want to use assertions on every scenarios mean time.So instead of ```global``` what else I can use.Please suggest.

Comment: I have edited the answer above. Can you check the assertion section in Gatling? I hope you can do it using the mean: perform the assertion on the mean of the metric.

Comment: can you please give me an example how to use groups in gatling assertions because i am not able to do assertions on group level basis.